# Can I travel to Korea with a one-way flight on a long-term visa?

Tags: south-korea, study

I will be studying in Korea this year and need to buy my ticket. My visa is a D-4 and I DO have plans on extending my visa and my studies. I don't want to buy my flight back just now so I don't end up wasting money (as it is really expensive).

I am trying to get this information but can't find it literally anywhere.

Comment: I visited many countries from 2014 to 2019 and never had to show a return ticket, even though I had read things here and elsewhere for some of them saying a return ticket is required to be allowed in.  One of those was Korea.  About half the trips, I did have a return ticket, but I was never asked to show it.  However, it's worth remembering that immigration officials usually have the option of being lenient or finicky.

Comment: @WGroleau i have read somewhere that it's only required in case you are entering the country under a tourist visa, but im really confused now...

Comment: My son moved from the US to the UK in 2017 with a UK Tier 2 visa for work. He had a one-way ticket. Airline staff refused to check him in because of his lack of a return flight. He escalated (politely!) to a supervisor, who checked him in for the one-way flight.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica im reading about companies like onward flight, one way fly etc. maybe it might work?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Korea specifically, but as a nearly universal rule worldwide, **long term/resident visas are excluded from return flight requirements**.

However, two one-way flights will almost always be more expensive than a return, so I'd advise you to check carefully if you would really save any money by buying flights separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed you can fly into Korea on a one-way ticket. I've done this quite a few times. Two one-way tickets are usually more expensive than round-trips, but if you're planning to stay a few years, it might make sense financially (and round-trip tickets usually don't last that long, or are expensive too).